# BigQuery doesn't update rows with NULL values

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

The code only update rows, which have key and value not null. But it doesn't update rows with null value.

```
UPDATE `xxx` 

SET project= (

    SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(

      ARRAY(

       SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE('entity' AS key, "value" AS value)

        FROM t.labels

      ) AS labels)

    FROM  UNNEST([project]) t

  )

where project.name like "%yyy%"
```

How should I be doing this (if it's possible) as i know that unnest don't include null value ?

Comment: First, you can use “IFNULL” statement to replace the NULL value for something you want like a field value or fixed value like this “IFNULL([name of field],'something you want' or [name of some field])”. Then you can update the fields.

Answer (score 0):

I have suffered from the same issue. To update an empty array, you should act like you are creating it.

```
UPDATE `xxx` 

SET project= (

    SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(

     (

       SELECT [("Entity","Value")]

      ) AS labels)

    FROM  UNNEST([project]) t

  )

where project.name like "%yyy%"
```